# How can I get a relation with multiple ways as members in addition to the members with Overpass QL?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

There's a relation I'd like to export via the Overpass API that happens to contain two ways as members. However, I'd like to export the relation along with the two member ways. I haven't been able to figure out how to modify this query to do this though:

**Overpass Query**

```
[out:json][timeout:25];

(
  relation["type"="building"](41.240076, -73.1221787, 41.7183459, -72.832613);
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

This query just returns the two member ways, but *not* the relation. How can I modify this query to return both the member ways and the containing relation?

Comment: When I run this on the overpass turbo website, I get data (see data tab there) containing a relation, with tags, two ways and all nodes. What else do you expect ?

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks ok, it even returns the relation as @escada already pointed out. Maybe you're having difficulties to parse this format in your application. In this case it may be worth looking at the `out geom;` modifier:

```
relation["type"="building"](41.240076, -73.1221787, 41.7183459, -72.832613);
out geom;
```

This will return all of your data in one single place:

```
  <relation id="5466069">
    <bounds minlat="41.3103714" minlon="-72.9276583" maxlat="41.3108385" maxlon="-72.9272647"/>
    <member type="way" ref="364538449" role="">
      <nd lat="41.3103714" lon="-72.9275906"/>
      <nd lat="41.3104313" lon="-72.9275477"/>
      <nd lat="41.3104550" lon="-72.9276003"/>
      <nd lat="41.3104318" lon="-72.9276174"/>
      <nd lat="41.3104378" lon="-72.9276309"/>
      <nd lat="41.3104006" lon="-72.9276583"/>
      <nd lat="41.3103714" lon="-72.9275906"/>
    </member>
    <member type="way" ref="347416244" role="">
      <nd lat="41.3108265" lon="-72.9272990"/>
      <nd lat="41.3108133" lon="-72.9272647"/>
      <nd lat="41.3107369" lon="-72.9273167"/>
      <nd lat="41.3107498" lon="-72.9273503"/>
      <nd lat="41.3107778" lon="-72.9273313"/>
      <nd lat="41.3108005" lon="-72.9273905"/>
      <nd lat="41.3108238" lon="-72.9273747"/>
      <nd lat="41.3108385" lon="-72.9273647"/>
      <nd lat="41.3108160" lon="-72.9273061"/>
      <nd lat="41.3108265" lon="-72.9272990"/>
    </member>
    <tag k="name" v="Bass Library Entrances"/>
    <tag k="type" v="building"/>
  </relation>
```

Try it in overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/bua